# Migrating wordpress multisite and domain mapping plugin

Tags: multisite, migration, domain-mapping, subdomains

I have a WordPress Multisite installation (with sub-domains). Plus I use [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) to have separate domain name for each subsite.

Now, I want to migrate all this to a new server (NO change in domain name). The potential problem I see is with domain mapping plugin. I cannot set the same domain name on the old server as well as new server at the same time. I think it will corrupt routing tables etc. Am I right? Do I have to use temporary domain names?

If you have done something like this please do share some suggestion to do this in the best possible way.

Comment: See this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/163103/170), you find all information about domain mapping without plugin and how it works. You need only a plugin, if you will use alias with domains.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not use temp domain names. You migrate all the files to the new server, then you update all the DNS records for the mapped domains to the new server.

Comment: Thanks for your message. Actually, I forgot to mention that I also need to test the new server before directing all my traffic there. What do you suggest in this case?