# Is this a job for WP MultiSite with domain mapping plugin?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I'm helping some folks convert an apartment management company's website from a custom CMS to Wordpress.  We're pretty far along in the process and I just need to figure out how to get this request to work.

Let's say that the company's main url is www.apartments.com and each of the 15 properties has a detail page like:

- www.apartments.com/property/oak-court
- www.apartments.com/property/pine-grove

and so on.

These use a custom post type called Property

They also own domains for each property like:

- www.oakcourtapartments.com
- www.pinegroveapartments.com

They want these domains to go an "apartment microsite" which is just a single page that looks like the detail page on the main site but with some caveats:

- This is NOT just redirecting the user.  The url is to remain oakcourtapartments.com etc.
- The body copy, title tag and meta tags should be different from the page on the main site so it isn't an SEO conflict.
- Editing both detail and micro should be done in the same place.  If the editor updated the hero image for Oak Court the change is reflected on both the detail page and the microsite on the front end.

I have custom fields on the Property post type like "microsite body", "microsite title" and also the various meta tabs so the editors can work as needed.

Would MultiSite help me here?  How about the domain mapping plugin.  I'm just not really sure how to tie everything together to make it work... if it even can work.

Comment: See this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/163103/170), you find all information about domain mapping without plugin and how it works. You need only a plugin, if you will use alias with domains.