# wordpress multisite with already existing subdomain

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I have activated the wordpress multisite in my main domain. Now I want to add an already existing subdomain with a separate wp installation. How can I do it?

Comment: You have to add the domain to the settings of the site, look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112818/how-to-use-alias-domain-for-multisite-installation/163103#163103

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use alias domain for multisite installation?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112818/how-to-use-alias-domain-for-multisite-installation)

Comment: are you asking how to merge them into a single install? A multisite is a single installation of WordPress that contains multiple sites, if you have multiple physical copies of WordPress those are multiple installations and can't be combined without migrating the site content/themes/plugins into one install that's a multisite. Doing that also involves server level changes that are unrelated to WordPress

Comment: @bueltge i did it yes, i can switch from my main domain to subdomain but i cannot switch back. Any idea why I don't see the multisite option on my subdomain dashboard?